# Perform condition on last record of table and get id of that record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to perform condition on last record of my below model :

```
 public partial class TestPart
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int TestId { get; set; }
       public int Status { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

**Query :**

```
var query = context.TestPart.OrderByDescending(tp=>tp.Id)
                                                .Take(1)
                                                .Where(tp => tp.TestId == 100 &&
                                                 tp.Status == 1 &&
                                                 tp.Jobs.All(j => j.Type == "Recurring")
```

Here I want to get Id of TestPart whose `status = 1 and all jobs are recurring` but this should only consider `checking last record of test part`

But I am unable to select Id of last TestPart in above query.

**Update :**

```
Id    TestId       Status     
1     100          1
2     100          2
3     100          0
4     100          1
5     101          1
```

so here I want to filter out data based on TestId and then select last record for that specific TEST and then check out whether all job types are recurring for that last selected TestPart id i.e in above case TestPartId=4.

Comment: `checking last record of test part` Can you clarify this? Or even a simple data example would help immensely in understand what exactly you want.

Comment: @Flater I have 10 records in my TestPart table so i want to select last record only of TestPart i.e 10th record and perform condition on it

Comment: So, whats not working?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten After my where condition i am unable to select TestPart Id

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused: I also see a `TestId` used (for which I assume one test has many testparts). When you say you want the last entry, do you mean the last testpart **of a given test**, or the last testpart **of the table**? These distinctions matter.

Comment: @Flater I updated my question with sample records and more description

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I updated my question with sample input and description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is a bit fragmented. In order to make sure that I'm answering to the right problem, these are my assumptions:

- One `Test` has many `TestPart` children.
- You want the last `TestPart` **of a given test**, not just the last entry of the table (regardless of test id).
- You're trying to ascertain if this last item fits the criteria, thus making the end result of your code a boolean value.

---

You need to split the **data retrieval** and **data validation** steps here.

When you merge them, you get different results. You ask for the last item that fits the criteria. This means that in a list of 10 items (numbered 1 through 10 chronologically) you might end up getting item **8** if it fits the criteria and 9 and 10 do not fit the criteria.

From your description, I surmise that's not what you want. You want to take item **10** (regardless of whether it fits the criteria, and **only then** check if this item fits the criteria or not.

Think of it this way:

> - I want the last person named John who entered this building.
> - I want to see if the last person who entered the building is named John.

Your code is trying to do the first. But what you really want to do is the second.

The correct version of your code:

```
//Get the last testpart of the test.
TestPart item = context.TestPart
                       .Include(tp => tp.Jobs)  //possibly optional dependent on lazy/eager loading.
                       .OrderByDescending(tp=>tp.Id)
                       .First(tp => tp.TestId == 100);

//Check if this item fits the criteria
bool isValid = 
          item.Status == 1 
          && item.Jobs.All(j => j.Type == "Recurring");
```

`isValid` contains your answer.

---

**Edit - just for completeness**

There are ways to merge this into one query, but this makes the code easily prone to misinterpretation.

```
bool isLastItemValid = context.TestPart
                          .Where(tp => tp.TestId == 100)
                          .OrderByDescending(tp => tp.Id)
                          .Take(1)
                          .Any(tp =>
                                   tp.Status == 1 
                                   && tp.Jobs.All(j => j.Type == "Recurring");
```

This gives you the same result. It relies on the "trick" that calling `Any()` on a list with only one item really just evaluates the one item.

While technically correct, I find this version unnecessarily complicated, less readable, and more prone to developer misinterpretation.

Comment: Your second assumption is correct : "You want the last TestPart of a given test, not just the last entry of the table (regardless of test id)."

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time :)

Comment: In your first version dont you think we should put First condition at the top to avoid ordering whole TestPart records unnecessarily?

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused: LINQ to a database does not execute (it only collects your operations) until you access the result (`First()`, at which point it executes your collected operations **all at once**). You could, if you really wanted to, `Where(tp => tp.TestId == 100)` and then do a `First()` (no parameter), but I don't think it functionally matters for LINQ, since it will only execute the combined operation when it needs to. (Some experts who closely inspect the queries that EF generates may disagree, but that's a highly detailed subject matter, seems out of scope for your case).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.Take(1).Where()` with `FirstOrDefault()`

```
TestPart item = context.TestPart.OrderByDescending(tp => tp.Id)
                       .FirstOrDefault(tp => tp.TestId == 100 &&
                                             tp.Status == 1 &&
                                             tp.Jobs.All(j => j.Type == "Recurring");
int result = item.Id;
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. This takes the first (or last) item that fits the criteria. This means that you don't know _which_ item you're getting from the table. From OP's description, I read that he definitively wants the first (or last) item, and then see if that item fits the criteria. (Note that I asked the OP to clarify because the explanation/code example is not the clearest)

Comment: @Flater **you don't know which item you're getting from the table** you get the latest, which was required by OP `OrderByDescending(tp => tp.Id)`

Comment: @fubo, No. You get the first row that satisfies the condition. that might not be the first row of `OrderByDescending(tp => tp.Id)`

Comment: @fubo: No, you get the latest **that fits the criteria**. There is a difference between "the last man who entered the building is named John" and "the last man named John who entered the building". The second example doesn't specify that John was the last to enter the building, only that he was **the last John** to enter the building.

Comment: @Flater there is a gap petween what the OP is asking and what he really wants

Comment: @fubo I couldn't say it better

Comment: @fubo: OP's phrasing makes it difficult, but he's not asking for the wrong thing. Other than omitting the `testId` from his explanation (which I do think is a mistake), what he explains is correct. Your interpretation is _similar_ but not what OP is describing.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate thing to do is break it into steps. I do love a big LINQ statement like the next guy, but only when it elegantly represents the required logic. In this case you're to get a record, check its status, and return its ID, so why not express that in ROC?

```
var lastPart = context.TestPart.OrderByDescending(tp=>tp.Id)
                      .First();

bool match =  (lastPart.TestId == 100 &&
               lastPart.Status == 1 &&
               lastPart.Jobs.All( j => j.Type == "Recurring"));

if (match) return lastPart.Id;
```

Relevant: [Writing ROC (Really Obvious Code)](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/09/01/no-comment-part-3.aspx).

Comment: That's a nice approach. Still need to add `FirstOrDefault` (and check for `null`) though

Comment: I updated my question with sample records and more description

Comment: The OP, just updated the question, which changes thing (again...) and this answer doesn't fit his needs.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time :)